# How to insert multiple jquery on created rows values into database using php and mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Here is my html code :

```
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Add More</button>
        </div>
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['form1'])) { 
  $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_products (itemNo,itemName,price,quantity,total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
  $statement->execute(array($_POST['itemNo'],$_POST['itemName'],$_POST['price'],$_‌​POST['quantity']); 
  $success_message = " inserted successfully."; } catch(Exception $e) { $error_message = $e->getMessage(); } 
}
```

And here is my jquery code that creats add more field :

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
```

`html = '<tr>';
html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '</tr>';
$('table').append(html);
i++;
});`

How can i insert database this 2 or 3 rows multiple values using php ?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you want to see ? but please help me i am having a great problem last 5 days .

Comment: post php code which you have tried to store multiple row in db

Comment: It can store only one not multiple if(isset($_POST['form1']))
{

    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_products (itemNo,itemName,price,quantity,total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    $statement->execute(array($_POST['itemNo'],$_POST['itemName'],$_POST['price'],$_POST['quantity']);

    $success_message = " inserted successfully.";
    
  
  }
  
  catch(Exception $e) { 
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  }
}

Comment: Please update your question with this information.

Comment: update with my php code

Comment: You cannot use $_POST['itemNo'],$_POST['itemName'] etc. Because they are in array format

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208001/how-to-make-array-for-add-multiple-row-in-a-sql-table-by-same-form

Comment: It may hold 5 or 10 rows values so i can use array ,,, see my jquery code . But how can i insert this array value ?

Comment: It fixed the form in html but my multiple rows created on jquery when click addmore btn then how can i know how many rows are created by jquery and insert them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count some of your field and try to iterate using `for` loop of that count and try to store its value by using `$i` variable of `for` loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['itemNo']);$i++)
{
    $data['itemNo']       = $_POST['itemNo'][$i];
    $data['itemName']     = $_POST['itemName'][$i];
    $data['price']        = $_POST['price'][$i];
    $data['quantity']     = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $data['total']        = $_POST['total'][$i];
    //your insert query here
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much ... It is so much helpful and i can successfully insert my multiple values.